# No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/contact_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

This is the error I get when I try to go to my contact page:
No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/contact_path"

This is my routes.rb.

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
get "static_pages/home"
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

This is my controller.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

This is on my file home.html.erb

<%= link_to "Contact", 'contact_path' %>

Note that the home page does not work when I use the match syntax for the home in the roots.rb. I switched it to the get method simply so I could keep working. I would like the match syntax to work as it's a technique I'm trying for my comsci class. Any thoughts as to why I'm not getting a root? I should have one according to my controller, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Your routes will create a `contact_path` helper *method*, you're using a string:

```
<%= link_to "Contact", 'contact_path' %>
# ---------------------^------------^
```

where you want to call the helper:

```
<%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>
```

If you pass a string to `link_to`, it will create an `<a href="contact_path">` link and that relative URL will get tacked onto the current URL to produce the stray `/static_pages/contact_path` URL that you're seeing.

Comment: Oop there we go. Terminal refreshing issues. Got it now. Thank you to all who helped, especially this comment, as you explained something my textbook didn't very well.

Answer (score 0):

the link_to should be

```
<%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>
```